# Memory alloc and free wrappers for a project

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am using the following wrapper functions for my project. I am going to use it in a lot of places. I have a doubt in mind to proceed with this function or instead use a macro or an inline function as I am going to use it in a lot of places. Can someone suggest what is best as I am going to use this code in a small embedded device. I am using the wrappers here to keep my code portable with different platforms.

```
void mem_deallocate(void **mem)
{
    assert(mem != NULL);

    if (*mem)
    {
        free(*mem);
        *mem = NULL;
    }
}


void *mem_allocate(size_t count, size_t size)
{
    void *mem = malloc(count * size);
    return mem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`free(ptr)` will do nothing if the `ptr` is `NULL`, so you could strip down your `mem_deallocate()` function to something like this:

```
void mem_deallocate(void **mem)
{
    assert(mem != NULL); 

    free(*mem);
    *mem = NULL;
}
```

This would save you any branching that goes on due to the `if`; and makes the function content quite small. The overhead of having this as a function rather than putting its contents inline would be best tested impirically.

Also in your `mem_allocate()` why don't you check for `NULL` in `mem` after the `malloc`? In its current format I don't see any advantage on running it over just using

```
void *mem = malloc(count * size);
```

straight in you code, without calling the function.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I will add them. Well I am using the wrappers here for one more advantage. It is easier for me to change the function at one place when I port this code to different platforms.

Comment: @C0D3R it would be useful to add that reason for using wrappers to the question, which you can edite.